# Cell array of strings - check elements in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

In Matlab, if I have a cell array of strings, how can I check if for example 3rd row and 1st column is equal to some given string, for example `'ABC'`?

For example, `myArray(3,1) == 'ABC'` gives me an error:

> Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
>
> Error in cw14 (line 19)
> if myArray(3,1) == 'ABC'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because you need to use {curly braces} in order to access the *content* of the cell array.

Using (regular brackets) indexes the actual *cell*, which in your case contains a string. Moreover, in order to check for the presence of strings I recommend using [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html?searchHighlight=strcmp) or maybe [strfind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html?searchHighlight=strfind).

Therefore use this:

```
strcmp(myArray{3,1},'ABC')
```

Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html?refresh=true) for infos about indexing into cell arrays.

**EDIT** (following comments)

Using logical `==` in order to find for strings into a cell array is not safe, because using this operator splits the strings and compares every letter forming it, as opposed to `strcmp` and the likes, that checks the whole string.

Consider this code, where I put some strings into `myArray`:

```
myArray = {'A' 'B' 'ABC' 'CBA' 'ABC'}.'

myArray = 

    'A'
    'B'
    'ABC'
    'CBA'
    'ABC'
```

If we apply  `==` on this cell array of strings as follows:

```
Check_31 = myArray{3,1} == 'ABC'

Check_41 = myArray{4,1} == 'CB_'
```

Matlab returns those 2 logical vectors:

```
Check_31 =

     1     1     1


Check_41 =

     1     1     0
```

So as you see, the character "_" is not the last element of the string present in the cell {4,1}.

Now if we use `strcmp` (on the whole cell array; we don't need to index specific cells to check whether some string is present):

```
Check_ABC = strcmp(myArray,'ABC')
```

We also get a logical vector, but this time not referring to the 3 letters forming the string inside the cell, but rather referring to the cell array itself and whether 'ABC' is present or not. The result is this:

```
Check_ABC =

     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
```

Which makes sense, since 'ABC' is indeed present in cells {3,1} and {5,1}.

Hope that's clearer!

Comment: myArray{3,1} == 'ABC' works fine, but if I do it in a loop, for example myArray{i,1} == 'ABC' (looping over i) it doesn't. It says matrix dimensions must agree. Why it doesn't work and why we have to use strcmp here?

Comment: What about strcmp(myArray{i,1},'ABC')?

Comment: With == you test every element of the character array {i,1} with all elements of the right hand side character array 'ABC'. To compare 'XYZ' == 'ABC' gives [0 0 0] but 'XY' == 'ABC' gives the error, because the dimensions don't agree (2 not the same as 3).

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Thanks @JaBe haha that's exactly it :)